# quickly package --extras doesn't produce /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/../share/locale

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, packaging

I'm trying to package an app to /opt, but when installed the app won't run and complains:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/drawers/bin/drawers", line 45, in <module>
    import drawers
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/drawers/drawers/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    locale.bindtextdomain('drawers', '/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/drawers/share/locale')
NameError: name 'locale' is not defined
```

I can't figure out what I need to change.  Is there a config file I need to alter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your application doesn't contain any internationalized strings (internationalized with gettext helper: _(). So no local is produced to the targeted system as there is nothing to translate!

See http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html for my information on gettext frmo python.

If your application doesn't contain any strings that you present to the user, you can remove the locale.bindtextdomain command in drawers/**init**.py

Comment: Thanks for your help... There actually isn't locale.bindtext command in the quickly template. Just deleting these lines from __init__.py worked:

    import gettext
    from gettext import gettext as _
    gettext.textdomain('drawers')

Note that commenting them out isn't good enough, they get replaced with the actual locale command text when packaged via quickly package --extras (not regular package).